# u-Boot VxWorks TFTP boot failure: " ERROR: booting os 'Unknown OS' (14) is not supported"

Tags: vxworks, u-boot, tftp, zynq

I am trying to boot VxWOrks using tftp for zynq.
I have set the enviroment varibles for ipaddr, serverip, netmask accordingly and files are loaded in RAM succesfully. however, i get the following error when trying to boot the vxWorks image. There is not problem with the VxWOrks image as i can successfully boot with these iamges when i write these files to SDcard and boot from the sdcard

```
zynq-uboot> bootm 0x5000000 - 0x4000000

#ERROR: booting os 'Unknown OS' (14) is not supported"
```

Here is a complete screen shot

```
zynq-uboot> setenv ipaddr 192.168.88.169;setenv serverip 192.168.88.88;setenv netmask 255.255.255.0
zynq-uboot> tftp 0x8000000 BOOT.bin

Trying to set up GEM link...
Phy ID: 01410E40
Resetting PHY...
PHY reset complete.
Waiting for PHY to complete auto-negotiation...
Link is now at 1000Mbps!
Using zynq_gem device
TFTP from server 192.168.88.88; our IP address is 192.168.88.169
Filename 'BOOT.bin'.
Load address: 0x8000000
Loading: T ########################
done
Bytes transferred = 345180 (5445c hex)
zynq-uboot> tftp 0x5000000 uVxWorks && tftp 0x4000000 zynq-7000.dtb

Using zynq_gem device
TFTP from server 192.168.88.88; our IP address is 192.168.88.169
Filename 'uVxWorks'.
Load address: 0x5000000
Loading: T T #################################################################
         #################################################################
         ###############################################################
done
Bytes transferred = 2829468 (2b2c9c hex)
Using zynq_gem device
TFTP from server 192.168.88.88; our IP address is 192.168.88.169
Filename 'zynq-7000.dtb'.
Load address: 0x4000000
Loading: #
done
Bytes transferred = 3588 (e04 hex)
zynq-uboot> bootm 0x5000000 - 0x4000000

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 05000000 ...
   Image Name:   vxWorks
   Image Type:   ARM Unknown OS Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    2829404 Bytes = 2.7 MiB
   Load Address: 00200000
   Entry Point:  00200000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
ERROR: booting os 'Unknown OS' (14) is not supported

zynq-uboot> <INTERRUPT>
```

Comment: Does net-booting use the same version & copy of U-Boot as the SDcard boot?  BTW when you mention that *"There is not problem ...when ... boot from the sdcard"*, I expected to see the output of a successful boot instead of a failed one.

Comment: What u-boot version are you using? What is the output of "mkimage -l uVxWorks"? The output of mkimage for "Image Type" should not be "Unknown". The error message shows "'Unknown OS' (14)" as the image type of the binary, but 14 is the definition for VxWorks image type so there should be no problem. Unless you are mixing tools and u-boot versions.

Comment: The U-boot version is U-Boot 2012.10 (Dec 17 2012 - 10:57:07)
I have solved the problem. It is not in the version. All i had to do was to load the vxWorks.bin as well

"zynq-uboot> tftp 0x200000 vxWorks.bin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOlution:
i had to  to load the vxWorks.bin as well and it worked.

```
zynq-uboot> tftp 0x200000 vxWorks.bin
```